# Getting data about a csv file in coldfusion

Tags: csv, coldfusion

Using coldfusion I am using a cvs file and then compiling multiple txt files form that depending on the value of each row in the csv file

I would like to do a SELECT DISTINCT on the csv for the Bank Name column if that is possible, I want to get the distinct values in that column withing the csv. I then also want to count how many rows there are for that distinct value (how many times it appears in the csv file). Finally I want to get the SUM of the Amount column for that distinct Bank Name

I am not really sure how to go about this and would appreciate any input and thank you in advance!

Comment: Ben Nadel has some good info about turning CSVs into query objects, then you can query-of-query them, or whatever you like: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/501-parsing-csv-values-in-to-a-coldfusion-query.htm

Comment: Thanks Chris! Thats a lot of code though, i would prefer to keep it as short as possible as i already have about 800 lines of code to process the csv but if there is no other short way that will have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your csv file using cfhttp.  The name attribute creates a query variable of the file contents which enables you to use query of queries.  Details are in the documentation of the cfhttp tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a datasource proxy with a text driver as is described in this post on [CSV files and ColdFusion](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2007/2/5/csv). Because of the 64bit and 32bit ODBC issues you may also need to refer to [this post](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/12/31/Access.on.64bit.ColdFusion) to get such a DSN installed on a modern CF installation. Note that the second post will work through CF 9, but I've not tested the technique on CF 10 or CF 11 (it's a pretty old technique).

I'm not recommending either approach but assuming you could get it working it *would* give you an easy way to use Q of a Q and get distinct values. I'm not sure if either one of them is any better than Ben's way of doing it. However, you can borrow his CFC and simply pass in your columns and data. I'm not sure I understand how that is more work than writing filtering code.